# Android textview breaks words apart when wrapping

Tags: android, xml, textview, word-wrap

I have a textview set to wrap text. The text is wrapping, but it is breaking words apart. How can I tell the textview to stop breaking words?

Here is the xml I have so far:

```
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/widget705"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/widget711"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/widget714"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="I am typing a bunch of text..."
android:ellipsize="start"
>
</TextView>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the [Ellipsize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setEllipsize%28android.text.TextUtils.TruncateAt%29) property of TextView.

Comment: Oops. Can you tell I'm new at this? I updated my question with the code I am using. I'm trying to see the change reflected in DroidDraw, which I have discovered to be more than a little buggy.